# jQuery and Table, grab every cell in the NTH column

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have your basic table layout (like below). How to I grab every NTH cell? I basically want to add a css class to the cells in column N.

So if I wanted all cells in column 2, I want to have a jQuery obj that contain the following cells that are marked:

```
<table>
    <tr class="trow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td> <!-- included -->
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td> <!-- included -->
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td> <!-- included -->
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try the [jQuery nth Cell selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild)...  Must be there!

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(n)").addClass("MyGreatClass");
```

Answer (score 5):

[nth Selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild)

```
$('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)').addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  The best way depends on how the table is generated and what you will be doing with the cells in javascript/JQuery.

You could add an id to each cell, something like "cell-*row*-*col*".  This allows you to grab any cell via document.getElementByID().