# How to grab every nth column of a row in a table and add a unique value to its attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that is meant to be a specific size, the value in the 5th cell of the table is always truncated and I want to add a `title` attribute that is the full value of the 5th cell.

I have been looking at some solutions such as:

[jQuery and Table, grab every cell in the NTH column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296832/jquery-and-table-grab-every-cell-in-the-nth-column?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Adding attribute in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But those aren't exactly what I want. I've tried this:

```
$('#tableID > tbody > tr:nth-child(n) > td:nth-child(5)').attr('title', 'hello');
```

And this does give every 5th cell and add the `title` attribute to it. But the problem is that I want to be able to get an array or list of the 5th cells and be able to make the `.text()` of the cell into the `title` attribute. I tried to put `$('#tableID > tbody > tr:nth-child(n) > td:nth-child(5)')` into a variable, but that doesn't give me the array.

Is there a way of getting the full list of 5th column of every row in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just loop over the collection with `each`:

```
$('#tableID > tbody > tr:nth-child(n) > td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
});
```

This code, in each iteration, takes the text of the cell and assigns it into the `title` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could just use the .each() function on it. I tried to do a for(;;) loop through it and i wasn't getting what I wanted so I assumed that didn't work.